# Can a signed arithmetic progression reach all integers?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, dynamic-programming

$F:=\big\{f\,\big|\,\text{function }f: \mathbf N\rightarrow \{1,2\}\big\}$. $S:=\big\{\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{f(i)}i\,\big|k\in\mathbf N, f\in F\big\}$. Is $S=\mathbf Z$?

I had thought of using dynamic programming to solve this problem. However, the fact that the number of summands $k$ is unbounded seems to make this unfeasible.

Comment: Consider $f$, defined by $f(i)=2$ if $i$ is odd, $f(i)=1$ if $i$ is even.. How does $\sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^{f(i)}\cdot i$ change as $k$ increases from $1$ to $\infty$?

Comment: notice that if $f(i) = 1$ and $f(i+1) = 2$, then you have a $+1$ in the sum. The opposite for the $-1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By induction, $S_k = \{\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{f(i)} i \mid f \in F\}$ consists of all integers $x$ with $|x| \le k(k+1)/2$ and $x \equiv k(k+1)/2 \mod 2$.